# How to predefine the length of a list

Tags: r

How can I create a list of size n? For example,  `lines = read.table(filename, sep="\n")` how would I create a list called `linesCopy` that is of the size of `lines`?

I tried something like `linesCopy <- [[length(lines)]]` but this throws `unexpected token [[`

Comment: Not clear. Why do you want a list? Do you mean a matrix with the same dimension as "lines"? A vector of the length of the number of rows/columns of "lines"?

Comment: `replicate(n, list(NULL))` or `rep(list(NULL), n)`

Answer (score 9):

A `list` is just a vector, you can create a list of any size using `vector()`.

For example, a list of size 4:

```
vector("list", 4)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Or, specific in your case, a list named `linesCopy` with the same size as the length of `lines`:

```
linesCopy <- vector("list", length(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
linesCopy         <- list()
length(linesCopy) <- length(lines)
```

might do what you want. There's probably a prettier way to do it, but I can't think of it off the top of my head.